# disable plugin activation on no multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite

how to restrict plugin activation only in multisite ?

my plugin must be activated only on a network.

Thx

> On registrer activation hook

```
If ( ! is_multisite() )
  wp_die(‘message’)
```

Comment: Throw an Exception on plugin activation if not inside a network?

Comment: thanks, but that's what I have been trying to do since this afternoon, but I can't do it correctly, the plugin activates anyway.

Comment: Perhaps showing the code you working with could help to find the 'error' ?

Comment: Actually I have a wp_die, I try to launch a notice and stop plug-in install.